# Selenium-grid remote driver how to modify headers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

How i can modify the request headers before sending request to website? I need authorize in website with JWT Bearer token. How i can do this?

driver initialization:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=f"http://{hostname}:{os.environ['SELENIUM_PORT']}",
                                       options=chrome_options)
... another code ...

self.driver.get(url)
```